# Marklogic DLS Document Checkout Timout

Tags: version-control, marklogic

Does MarkLogic DLS offer a similar file versioning experience to subversion?

Under Subversion, once the file(document) has been locked, others could not update it anymore, unless the file has been committed (check-in) or released the lock.

However in MarkLogic Library Services (DLS), once the document has been checked out, others could still call `dls:document-checkout-update-checkin` to update and release the lock. Does it mean it is the developer who should use those dls functions to implement the file lock and unlock mechanism?

I tried to use the `timeout` parameter in [dls:doucment-checkout](https://docs.marklogic.com/dls:document-checkout). However, it seems the document will **remain in the checkout status forever**. But I do see that parameter when I call 'dls:coument-checkout-status'.
[image: dls check out status]

Does it mean that it is the developer who should check the server timestamp together with the initial checkout timestamp and timeout duration to determine whether the file is still in lock status?

If so, I will need to write some XQuery programs and set up a scheduled task in ML to clean up the file checkout daily. Is my above understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/dls#id_56448, I believe the timeout is not enforced automatically - i.e. there's no background process in MarkLogic that is periodically inspecting documents to see if they should be automatically checked back in or un-checked out. The timeout appears to be meant to be used by a developer to apply their own logic with it - e.g. allowing a UI to state that "Jane checked this document out and only intended to keep it for 10 minutes, but that was 2 hours ago - would you like to break her checkout?"